# Google speech Api v1 not working?

Tags: android, google-api, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, android-speech-api

I have developed an app using the Google speech Api v1

> https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1&client=chromium&lang="+language_code;

and this link was used to get the response. It was working fine but just from today it's not working. I am not getting any response from that link. Any one have any idea? Is there any alternative links? Please help

```
  protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String urlString = "https://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?xjerr=1&client=chromium&lang="
            + language_code;
//      String urlString = "https://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?    output=json&lang="+language_code+"s&key=AIzaSyCnl6MRydhw_5fLXIdASxkLJzcJh5iX0M4";

//      Log.e("SpeechRecognizer  url : ", urlString);
//       String urlString =
//       "https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1&client=speech2text&lang="
//       + language_code;
    URL url;
    try {
        Log.e("", "started speech to text");

        FLAC_FileEncoder fileEncoder = new FLAC_FileEncoder();

        File inputfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getPath() + "/SpeechLibrary/speech.wav");
        File outputfile = new File(Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                + "/SpeechLibrary/speech.flac");

        fileEncoder.encode(inputfile, outputfile);

        url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setDefaultUseCaches(true);
        con.setConnectTimeout(20000);

        con.setReadTimeout(60000);
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        // con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
        // "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "audio/x-flac;rate=16000");
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getPath() + "/SpeechLibrary/speech.flac");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        fis.read(buffer);
        fis.close();
        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
        os.write(buffer);
        os.close();

        con.connect();
        con.getResponseMessage();
           InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String s;
        StringBuilder resultContent = new StringBuilder();

        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            resultContent.append(s + "\n");
        }
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(resultContent.toString());
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("hypotheses");
        Log.e("Response String: ", resultContent.toString());
        if (jsonArray.length() != 0) {

            output = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("utterance");
            confidence_level = Double.parseDouble(jsonArray
                    .getJSONObject(0).getString("confidence"));
        } else if (jsonArray.length() == 0) {

        }
        // output=resultContent.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        output = "";
        confidence_level = -1;
        e.printStackTrace();

        Log.e("ERROR IN PARSING:", e.toString());
        if (e.toString().contains("java.net.UnknownHostException:")||e.toString().contains("java.net.SocketException")) {

            return "NETWORK ISSUE";
        }

    }
    return null;
}
```

Is anyone else having the same problem?.

Comment: no response, and no error ?

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1 this is what I am getting and the response is null

Comment: Time to switch to version 2 ?

Comment: version 2 is same as the version 1 .I just tried https://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?xjerr=1&client=chromium&lang="+language_code; but still it's showing the same error.

Comment: can u provide me any link.

Comment: Can you post your codes? And double check with your network connection to Google? I'm okay to connect to the API (v1 & v2)

Comment: it was working till yesterday.I will post my code please see the edit.

Comment: Yes, google started to block extensive API users, consider switching to something else.

Comment: hmm is there any alternative methods.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Recently Google closed v1 API. V2 API now requires a key and streaming v2 API is limited to 50 requests per day. You can get a key as described here:

http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys

However there are no guarantees on unlimited usage.

https://github.com/gillesdemey/google-speech-v2

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a Java API check [this](https://github.com/The-Shadow/java-speech-api) one out. It supports the new Duplex API and V2 API. Comes with a handy tutorial as well. Might be a good idea to migrate before Google shuts down V1 for good if they haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

It is NOT possible to get additional quota for Chrome's Speech API. 
Look at the [Cloud Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/) instead.

Do NOT post to any Chromium groups/mailing lists for questions about the Speech API.