# Google Speech to Text API not working

Tags: linux, speech-recognition, wget, speech-to-text

In few recent days I am facing using using google speech to text API in linux.
Previously it works fine. but now there is not response from the server.

I am using the script below..

```
wget -q -U "Mozilla/5.0" --post-file sound.flac --header "Content-Type: audio/x-flac; rate=16000" -O - "http://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?lang=en-us&client=chromium" | cut -d\" -f12  > googleresponse.txt
```

Anyone facing same issue.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

V1 isn't working anymore. You'll have to switch to V2.

More Information can be found here:
[Google speech Api v1 not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511015/google-speech-api-v1-not-working)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.