# urlopen, Google speech API

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition, broken-pipe

I want to use Google's Speech API using the Python code below and a wav file (or an audio file in some other format for that matter). I get a broken pipe error at the moment, which I don't know how to fix. Have been reading a bit about changing headers [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html?highlight=urllib#headers), but feel I would need some guidance there if this is the way forward. Don't know if this is actually supposed to work, using the [Google Web Speech API Demo](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html?highlight=urllib#headers):

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import json
import scipy.io.wavfile

try:
    filename = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    print('Usage: transcribe.py <file>')
    sys.exit(1)

rate, data = scipy.io.wavfile.read(filename)

url = 'https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html'
headers = {'Content-type': 'audio/wav; rate=16000'}
# Possibly use this somehow later on...
# user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'
# values = {'name' : 'Michael Foord',
          'location' : 'Northampton',
          'language' : 'Python' }

req = urllib.request.Request(url, data, headers)

try:
    ret = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
except urllib.error.URLError as e:
    print(e.reason)
    sys.exit(1)

resp = ret.read()
text = json.loads(resp)['hypotheses'][0]['utterance']
print(text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url you use is not correct API url, the url for v1 speech API is https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize, however, it is turned down for quite some time already. See for details

[Google speech Api v1 not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511015/google-speech-api-v1-not-working)

You might want to use streaming API v2 with Google, but those requires API key, see for details https://github.com/gillesdemey/google-speech-v2

Overall, I recommend you to use existing wrapper instead, it will hide all API complexity. This wrapper should be good:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/

You still need an API key from google.

Alternatively you can use other API endpoint, like Project Oxford from Microsoft.

Comment: OK, thanks! It seems like there is no longer an API key for Google Speech though. I will look into other alternatives like Mozilla's Web Speech API and Project Oxford!